# Sub-domain causing issue in uploading file to dropbox

Tags: subdomain, dropbox

I am trying to upload files to dropbox from my website using Drop-Ins provided by dropbox. While creating app on dropbox for this I have added Drop-Ins domain "www.mydomain.com". But now, my website URL contains sub-domain like "www.subdomain.mydomain.com". This sub-domain changes with the users.

When I try to upload to Dropbox from such URL then dropbox is responding with error message **Origin does not match any app domain**. I know it is because of URL registered (while creating app on drop-box) is different then URL from where I am trying to upload.

So, how can I upload files to dropbox from URL which contains sub-domain and it (sub-domain) changes with users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you should be able to just [register](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps) the bare domain, for example, mydomain.com, which would enable use on any subdomain of mydomain.com, e.g., subdomain.mydomain.com, subdomain2.mydomain.com, www.subdomain.mydomain.com, etc.

Comment: Greg, this worked with dropbox. Now I am facing same problem with google drive. I tried same workaround with it but google apps don't allow URLs without http. They allow proper URL like "http://www.example.com"  Please help me in this too.

Comment: Sorry, I can only offer help with Dropbox. You may want to post a new question with the specifics and tag for Google Drive.